# Flutter ML-Kit BarcodeScanner returns old result. How do I stop this?

Tags: flutter, camera, google-mlkit

The sample below uses the Flutter `camera` & `google_mlkit_barcode_scanning` packages to detect a barcode.

The issue is that often it immediately returns an old result when the `Scan Barcode` button is pressed on the `Home` page while the camera is not pointing at any barcodes.

At around 22 seconds into this [Screen Recording](https://youtube.com/shorts/LbTHKZER9bQ) you can see there is no barcode in the camera preview but the previous barcode result is then quickly shown as detected.

Physical Testing Procedure:

1. Launch app.
2. Point camera ***AWAY*** from any potential barcodes.
3. Press `Scan Barcode` button => app navigates to `BarcodeScanPage` and starts image stream
4. Point camera ***AT*** barcode => barcode is detected and image stream is stopped
5. Navigate back to `Home` page.
6. Point camera ***AWAY*** from any potential barcodes again.
7. Return to step 3 and repeat...

After a small number of iterations (usually on the second visit to `BarcodeScanPage` on my old Pixel 2, or after around a dozen visits on a more recent Samsung Galaxy s21) the `BarcodeScanner` returns the previously scanned result while the camera is still pointing ***AWAY*** from any barcodes!!!

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BarcodeScanner Issue',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const BarcodeScanPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Scan Barcode'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BarcodeScanPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BarcodeScanPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<BarcodeScanPage> createState() => BarcodeScanPageState();
}

class BarcodeScanPageState extends State<BarcodeScanPage> {
  /// Used to control the cameras on the device.
  late CameraController _controller;

  /// The current selected camera to use.
  late CameraDescription _currentCamera;

  /// The scanned [Barcode] if any.
  Barcode? _barcode;

  /// Indicates if the async initialization is complete.
  bool _initializing = true;

  /// Indicates if an [InputImage] is currently being processed.
  bool _isBusy = false;

  /// ML-Kit Barcode Scanner.
  final BarcodeScanner _barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanner();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    debugPrint('BarcodeScanPageState: initState()');
    _initCamera();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    debugPrint('BarcodeScanPageState: dispose()');
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Barcode Scan')),
      body: Center(
        child: _initializing
            ? const Text('Initializing...')
            : _barcode == null
                ? CameraPreview(_controller)
                : Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Barcode detected'),
                      const SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                      Text(_barcode!.displayValue ?? 'Unknown'),
                    ],
                  ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Initialize camera and controller, and start image stream.
  Future _initCamera() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    _currentCamera = cameras.firstWhereOrNull((camera) {
          return camera.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back &&
              camera.sensorOrientation == 90;
        }) ??
        cameras.firstWhere((camera) {
          return camera.lensDirection == CameraLensDirection.back;
        });

    _controller = CameraController(
      _currentCamera,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
    );
    await _controller.initialize();
    await _controller.startImageStream(_processCameraImage);

    setState(() => _initializing = false);
  }

  /// Process a [CameraImage] into an [InputImage].
  Future _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) async {
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (final Plane plane in image.planes) {
      allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }
    final bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

    final Size imageSize = Size(
      image.width.toDouble(),
      image.height.toDouble(),
    );

    final imageRotation = InputImageRotationValue.fromRawValue(
      _currentCamera.sensorOrientation,
    );
    if (imageRotation == null) return;

    final inputImageFormat = InputImageFormatValue.fromRawValue(
      image.format.raw,
    );
    if (inputImageFormat == null) return;

    final planeData = image.planes.map(
      (Plane plane) {
        return InputImagePlaneMetadata(
          bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
          height: plane.height,
          width: plane.width,
        );
      },
    ).toList();

    final inputImageData = InputImageData(
      size: imageSize,
      imageRotation: imageRotation,
      inputImageFormat: inputImageFormat,
      planeData: planeData,
    );

    final inputImage = InputImage.fromBytes(
      bytes: bytes,
      inputImageData: inputImageData,
    );

    _processInputImage(inputImage);
  }

  /// Process [InputImage] for [Barcode].
  Future _processInputImage(InputImage inputImage) async {
    if (_isBusy) return;
    _isBusy = true;
    final barcodes = await _barcodeScanner.processImage(inputImage);
    if (barcodes.isNotEmpty) {
      await _controller.stopImageStream();
      await _controller.dispose();
      setState(() => _barcode = barcodes.first);
    }

    _isBusy = false;
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```
  camera: ^0.10.0+1
  collection: ^1.16.0
  google_mlkit_barcode_scanning: ^0.4.0
```

Below is a typical run log where this has occurred (Tested on an Android Pixel 2).
I have included debug statements in the `init` & `dispose` of the `BarcodeScanPage` to help follow  the sequence of events.

- In the first visit to the `BarcodeScanPage` in this log the barcode scanned as expected.
- In the second visit to the `BarcodeScanPage` in this log the `BarcodeScanner` returned the previously scanned `Barcode` while the camera was still pointing away from any barcodes.

```
I/flutter (13032): BarcodeScanPageState: initState()
I/CameraManagerGlobal(13032): Connecting to camera service
W/Camera  (13032): The selected imageFormatGroup is not supported by Android. Defaulting to yuv420
I/Camera  (13032): startPreview
I/Camera  (13032): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  (13032): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  (13032): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  (13032): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
W/Gralloc4(13032): allocator 3.x is not supported
W/Gralloc3(13032): allocator 3.x is not supported
I/Camera  (13032): startPreviewWithImageStream
I/Camera  (13032): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  (13032): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  (13032): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  (13032): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
I/Camera  (13032): CameraCaptureSession onClosed
W/System  (13032): A resource failed to call release. 
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(13032): Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) with jobId=1208757821 in 86400000ms(Backend next call timestamp 0). Attempt 1
I/ra_stream_issu(13032): Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
I/DynamiteModule(13032): Considering local module com.google.mlkit.dynamite.barcode:10000 and remote module com.google.mlkit.dynamite.barcode:0
I/DynamiteModule(13032): Selected local version of com.google.mlkit.dynamite.barcode
I/TetheringManager(13032): registerTetheringEventCallback:au.com.soundconception.camera_stream_issue
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(13032): Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(13032): Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(13032): Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(13032): Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) with jobId=1203777084 in 259261ms(Backend next call timestamp 1661840669048). Attempt 1
I/ra_stream_issu(13032): Background concurrent copying GC freed 6988(483KB) AllocSpace objects, 22(28MB) LOS objects, 23% free, 79MB/103MB, paused 353us total 147.579ms
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(13032): Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(13032): Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
I/tflite  (13032): Initialized TensorFlow Lite runtime.
I/native  (13032): I0830 15:50:09.888608   13236 oned_decoder_client.cc:685] barhopper::deep_learning::OnedDecoderClient is created successfully.
E/libc    (13032): Access denied finding property "ro.hardware.chipname"
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(13032): Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(13032): Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(13032): Storing event with priority=VERY_LOW, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(13032): Upload for context TransportContext(cct, VERY_LOW, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
I/ra_stream_issu(13032): Background concurrent copying GC freed 4314(1147KB) AllocSpace objects, 86(103MB) LOS objects, 23% free, 79MB/103MB, paused 194us total 131.504ms
I/Camera  (13032): startPreview
I/Camera  (13032): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  (13032): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  (13032): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  (13032): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
I/Camera  (13032): dispose
I/Camera  (13032): close
I/Camera  (13032): open | onClosed
I/flutter (13032): BarcodeScanPageState: dispose()
I/flutter ( 8761): is subscribed? false
I/flutter (13032): BarcodeScanPageState: initState()
I/Camera  (13032): close
W/Camera  (13032): The selected imageFormatGroup is not supported by Android. Defaulting to yuv420
I/Camera  (13032): startPreview
I/Camera  (13032): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  (13032): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  (13032): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  (13032): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
I/Camera  (13032): startPreviewWithImageStream
I/Camera  (13032): CameraCaptureSession onClosed
I/Camera  (13032): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  (13032): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  (13032): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  (13032): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore(13032): Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler(13032): Upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
I/Camera  (13032): startPreview
I/Camera  (13032): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  (13032): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  (13032): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  (13032): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  (13032): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
I/Camera  (13032): dispose
I/Camera  (13032): close
I/Camera  (13032): open | onClosed
W/System  (13032): A resource failed to call release. 
I/flutter ( 8761): wasAuthenticated: true, isAuthenticated true
I/flutter ( 8761): wasAuthenticated: true, isAuthenticated true
I/flutter ( 8761): wasAuthenticated: true, isAuthenticated true
```

I have tried clearing the image cache between visits to the `BarcodeScanPage` with the following code, but it does not change the result:

```dart
    imageCache.clearLiveImages();
    imageCache.clear();
```

I have also tried adding a global `previousCameraImage` variable and compared the current image byte data to the previous image byte data to see if the same image is being served, by making the following code additions:

```dart
...
CameraImage? previousCameraImage;

class BarcodeScanPage extends StatefulWidget {
...
Future _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) async {
    final isPreviousCameraImage =
        image.planes.firstWhereIndexedOrNull((index, plane) {
              return !listEquals(
                plane.bytes,
                previousCameraImage?.planes[index].bytes,
              );
            }) ==
            null;
    debugPrint(
      '_processCameraImage isPreviousCameraImage: $isPreviousCameraImage',
    );
    if (isPreviousCameraImage) return;

    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    ...
```

*NOTE: The `CameraImage` class does not implement an equality operator, so I believe the above is a reasonable alternative, but am happy to be corrected!*

When I run the test with this code change `isPreviousCameraImage` never resolves to `true` and the main issue still occurs.

This result, combined with the fact that the [Screen Recording](https://youtube.com/shorts/LbTHKZER9bQ) shows that the camera is not pointing at a barcode when the second "barcode detection" occurs, would suggest that the issue may be with the `google_mlkit_barcode_scanning` package.

If nobody has any solutions, I would also appreciate any suggestions for further investigation. I will also be posting this as an issue to the `google_mlkit_barcode_scanning` package developer shortly if I'm unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual issue is the `CameraController`.

I checked by converting the `CameraImage` that had been used each time a successful `BarcodeScanner` result was obtained, into a png, and displayed it next to the successful barcode result.

From this I could see that occasionally when you call `_controller.startImageStream(_processCameraImage)` the very first image returned is sometimes identical to the last image returned when you previously stopped the stream with `_controller.stopImageStream()`. In other words, the stream is not always cleared when it is restarted.

#### Solution:

A simple, safe and quick solution is to always discard the very first image delivered after calling `_controller.startImageStream(_processCameraImage)`.

```dart
class BarcodeScanPageState extends State<BarcodeScanPage> {
    ...
    // Indicates whether the first `CameraImage` from the Image Stream has been discarded.
    bool _firstImageDiscarded = false;
    ...

    /// Process a [CameraImage] into an [InputImage].
    Future _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) async {
        // Check if the first CameraImage has been discarded
        if (!_firstImageDiscarded) {
            // Update the boolean flag to true.
            _firstImageDiscarded = true;
            // Return immediately without processing the image, effectively discarding it.
            return;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I simply discard the very first image in this example?

Comment: @user2870829 I've updated the answer with an example. It may help to think of the image stream as a video, and we're just not doing any processing on the first frame.

Comment: Thanks for your example! Additionaly I was seeing that when I am not disposing the controller, the bug is not appearing.